# HTML5 Background Video Sizes?

Tags: html, video, background

I want a HTML5 background video with 100% width and 600px in height. The problem I got is when I make it 600 in height it scales the entire video down, so its no longer 100% in width. Any ideas on how to get round this issue?

Comment: Wouldn't that only be possible if you break the aspect ratio of the video? Are you sure that's what you want? Either way, if you provide your code or a link to it live it's easier to help.

Comment: like @jacob just mentioned, based off what you're saying you want to do, you would need to break the aspect ratio. I would advise against that. Code??????????????

Answer (score 0):

I assume you don't want to break the aspect ratio? So I guess you want to keep the video 100 % wide but "crop" it so that the area where the video is visible is 600px in height?

You can put the video inside a div:

```
<div class="wrapper"><video><source src="my-video.mp4"></video></div>
```

Then set the overflow-y attribute of wrapper div to "hidden":

```
.wrapper{width:100%;height:600px;overflow-y:hidden;}
video{width:100%;height:auto;position:absolute}
```

To position the video (ie. center it), use "top" and "left" attributes as well as "transform" -attributes (translateY, translateX).